# Update li values getting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have this list of li that have the rel tag with the index value. When the user edit the list I want the li to reflect that update. The ul li loop I am doing is getting undefined. Is there anything else I need to do to be able to see the li like adding the div?

[image]

Code

```
          $("#guideline-form").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('guideline-form submit');

            var data = currentGuidelineData;
            console.log(data);
            if (!data) {
                $('.guideline-not-selected').show();
                return;
            }
            console.log('Each');
            $('ul li').each(function (i) {
                var x = $(this).attr('rel'); 
                console.log(x);
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript, you're looking for `ul li` but in your HTML, you're using `<ol>`.
Try changing your javascript to `$('ol li')`

Also, if you have multiple lists, you might want to access it with a class or something else.

```
<ol class="myList">
    <li rel="1">...</li>
</ol>

$('.myList li').each(...)
```